# How valuable are logic test results during developers' recruiting process?

Tags: recruitment, software-development

I was recently asked to take a logic test (it seems a lot like IQ test) from Alva Labs by the recruiter. I scored 6 of 10 (which is considered average).

However, right before that I had another test - the coding session which consisted of 3 problems. It had easy-medium difficulty (comparing to leetcode) and I managed to write 100% passing solutions for all of the problems.

So I performed well at algorithms and coding session and did "average" at logic test. I would like to know, which is more valuable for an employer? I did not have receive feedback on my logic test result yet, but it seems like the job I am applying to has an IQ minimum requirement, which is frustrating, since I have never been good at such tests.

Comment: You'd have to ask the employer in question. We don't know what they value.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere first guess - don't hire people too much smarter than what the job needs. They'll get unusually bored and make everyone's life difficult, especially their own. I have used GPA caps for roles that needed what one might call an enterprising nature and independent thinking and a relative lack of risk aversion.

Comment: Just because there's a cap doesn't mean there's no floor ;-) Plus standardized tests make many people nervous anyway.

Comment: I used a wrong word for this, I mean that there is an IQ restriction, meaning that people with IQ lower than X are not the fit for the company

Comment: Not saying you did this but you could have taken a naive approach without taking into account time and space complexity so just because your algorithm solutions passed doesn't mean to say they were what the company was looking for.

Comment: @OldNick it has test cases against naive solutions and I also was told "well done!" by the recruiter. However I did not mentioned this in my question so I understand your doubts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every employer treats these type of tests differently. Some put incredible weight on these tests at this stage of the hiring process. Some put so little weight on these tests that they never even conduct them.

Each employers hiring process is different. It can even differ by position or even hiring manager within each company.

In your specific case, you will find out soon enough if the scores on the tests were enough to move you to the next stage. The passing scores can even differ by the number of people that are applying for the job. If the goal of the tests is to dump 90% of the resumes, then average might not be good enough. But if the goal is to only weed out the absolute worst of the candidates, then average is fine.

Comment: A mate of mine took one of these logic tests. Two days later, he interviewed with another company and was given literally the identical logic test. They told him that he had the highest test score they had ever seen :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is approached logically - logic tests are more valuable where the person might be expected to handle situations he has not encountered in the past. For a developer, this can be architecture, infrastructure, business, design, etc. If someone does well at coding and algo, but bad (average) at logic, it might mean they are suited only to being a dev, but not to other broader roles.

The above is one way of looking at it. There are other interpretations - e.g. just as a filtering mechanism.